# how to make the selenium to wait till item is selected in the litbox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My script is getting failed to select the item from a list box, this problem i am facing when i execute the script first time, for next time there is no problem.In console the message printed like

> "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException"

Here is my code

```
public void primarydign(final String diagnosis) throws InterruptedException{
        primarydiag.sendKeys(diagnosis);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-3']")));
    }
```

here is my html

can i use fluentwait instead of Webdriverwait can any one help me plz
    thanks in advance
    srinuvas m

Comment: Post the html code or link to the application. And elementToBeClickable is not the one you want.

Comment: <input id="PrimaryDiagnosis" class="form-control input-sm ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="" required="True" placeholder="Primary Diagnosis" name="PrimaryDiagnosis" data-bind="value: PrimaryDiagnosis" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off"/>

Comment: this is autocomplete listbox                                                                           <ul id="ui-id-6" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" tabindex="0" style="display: block; width: 827px; top: 405px; left: 374px;">

Comment: add those details to the question and what framework you are using

Comment: pom i am using and primarydign() method i am calling in another class

Comment: [edit] your question with all the details

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` looks like dynamic generated as you provided `By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-3']")` to locate the present time the id of your `listbox` seems as `ui-id-6` as you provided in the comment. So in this case you can not locate the `listbox` using `id`. try using `cssSelector` as below :-

```
public void primarydign(final String diagnosis) throws InterruptedException{
        primarydiag.sendKeys(diagnosis);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ul.ui-autocomplete.ui-front.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content")));
        element.click();
}
```

Hope it will work...:)